# Proving constant-time algorithm to find $A_n \mod 50$ as a linear combination of the $k$ previous $A$ terms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, recursive-algorithms

I've got the below scenario, based on a practice problem:

Suppose a sequence of integers $A_n$, and $A_0,\ldots,A_{k-1}< 50$ are all given, and each $A_i$ is a linear combination of the previous $k$ terms, i.e., $A_i = A_{i-1} b_1 + A_{i-2} b_2 + \dots + A_{i-k} b_k$. We know $A_0$ through $A_{k-1}$ and coefficients $b_1$ through $b_k$.

I already did what the practice problem asked but I want extend this further logically.

I want to figure out how to **prove** how $A_n \mod 50$ can be done in less than $ O(\log n)$ time. I programmed and plotted a basic scenario where $k=2$; $A_0, A_1, b_1, b_2$ are randomly generated; and 40 values of $A_n \mod 50$ are plotted

What I noticed was that sometimes these values repeated -- but are varying intervals. And some didn't seem to repeat at all, even when I adjusted to plot 1000 values.

I know, that logically and since we're doing mod 50 each time, we can find $A_n \mod 50$ in constant time as a function of the constant $k$ (rather than n). Intuitively it makes sense.

But then how would one prove this if the repeated interval varies depending on the values you start with? Is there some recurrence relation we can set up? Some mathematical inductive proof?

Basically, in this scenario, how do you prove an algorithm to find $A_n \mod 50$ exists in constant time and that the algorithm is correct and complete?

Comment: Since $A_n$ depends on the previous $k$ values, not just the last value, finding a repeated value in the sequence tells nothing about how it is going to continue. But if the whole $k$-sequence repeats after some period $t$, *then* you know that sequence is going to repeat itself forever with that period.

Comment: @mihaild mostly, thank you! I think the one thing Im still confused about is how to "prove" mathematically that it will eventually repeat. I get that once you determine it will repeat then you can make the conjectures about the period and everything, but that initial step of reasoning is a little lost on me

Comment: @Manny if at some point $k$ values in row repeat, then next value will repeat too, so will next, and so on - thus we will have period. And as there are finitely many possibilities what last $k$ values can be, they will necessarily repeat.